# Find the length of a Collatz conjecture sequence

Tags: python

I am trying to find the length of a Collatz conjecture sequence but my answer is wrong....
What's wrong with my code? I could not find relevant solution on the internet...

```
a=int(input())
mylist=[]
while a != 1:
    if a%2 == 0:
        a = a/2
    else:
        a = a*3 + 1
        mylist.append(a)
print(len(mylist))
```

Input:`6`

Output:`2`

If I input 6, the answer should be 9. I am trying to put them into a list and then find the length of the list.

Comment: Think carefully about when `mylist.append(a)` should happen in your code, and about when it actually does happen. Alternately, try displaying the list itself - instead of just the length - and see if you notice anything unusual about it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what exactly the issue is? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation is off:

```py
a=int(input())
6
mylist=[]
while a != 1:
    if a%2 == 0:
        a = a/2
    else:
        a = a*3 + 1
    mylist.append(a) # HERE
print(len(mylist))
```

Python distinguishes code blocks using indentation. Because of the wrong indentation, `mylist.append(a)` would only run in the `else` branch and would not add any of the even numbers. You could print `mylist` and notice that.

Also, it would probably be better to use `//` (integer division) instead of `/` (float division) to keep `a` integer.